# How can I layer an absolutely-positioned element between children of a sibling element?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, styles, z-index

I am using vue-slick-carousel package.

I have three main elements with which I want to interact. The first one is a picture with a character with the class `slide__person` The second one is a text with the class `slide__text` and a picture with a cloud with the class `banner__slider-cloud`.

I need the text to overlap the cloud, and the cloud, in turn, overlaps the picture with the person.

The cloud must remain static and cannot be moved inside the slider

I want to achieve something like this.

```
.banner__slider-cloud {
   z-index: 1;
}

.slide__text {
    z-index: 2;
}

.slide__person {
   z-index: 0;
}
```

I tried different options, interacted with the `z-index` property, tried to apply the `position` property, but I could not solve this problem

**You can also see my code in the online sandbox** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-water-n5b9c6?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:1574-1594)

```
<script>
import VueSlickCarousel from "vue-slick-carousel";
import "vue-slick-carousel/dist/vue-slick-carousel.css";
// optional style for arrows & dots
import "vue-slick-carousel/dist/vue-slick-carousel-theme.css";

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",

  components: { VueSlickCarousel },
};
</script>

<template>
  <div class="lending">
    <main class="banner">
      <div class="banner__slider">
        <VueSlickCarousel :arrows="true" :dots="true">
          <div class="slide">
            <div>
              <img
                class="slide__person"
                src="https://www.wikihow.com/images/6/61/Draw-a-Cartoon-Man-Step-15.jpg"
              />

              <p class="slide__text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Aliquam architecto, corporis deserunt distinctio dolor dolores
                ea ex hic iste magnam nihil optio perferendis perspiciatis
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="slide">
            <div>
              <img
                class="slide__person"
                src="https://www.wikihow.com/images/6/61/Draw-a-Cartoon-Man-Step-15.jpg"
              />

              <p class="slide__text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Aliquam architecto, corporis deserunt distinctio dolor dolores
                ea ex hic iste magnam nihil optio perferendis perspiciatis
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </VueSlickCarousel>

        <img class="banner__slider-cloud" src="../assets/cloud.png" />
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.slick-slide > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slide {
  max-width: 500px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.slide .slide__text {
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 8px;
}

.banner__slider-cloud {
  border: 1px solid;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 5%;
}
</style>
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.slick-slide>div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slide {
  max-width: 500px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.slide .slide__text {
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 8px;
}

.banner__slider-cloud {
  border: 1px solid;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="lending">
  <main class="banner">
    <div class="banner__slider">
      <div class="slide">
        <div>
          <img class="slide__person" src="https://www.wikihow.com/images/6/61/Draw-a-Cartoon-Man-Step-15.jpg" />

          <p class="slide__text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto, corporis deserunt distinctio dolor dolores ea ex hic iste magnam nihil optio perferendis perspiciatis
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <img class="banner__slider-cloud" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" />
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: I added a snippet demo. Does it accurately show your situation?

Comment: The primary problem is that you're trying to interleave a layer which is a sibling of an element between children of that other element. If you think about it in a physical context, it's a bit like trying to slot a vinyl record between two other records which are _inside_ a closed paper sleeve. 'T'ain't possible.

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` only works on elements within the same [stacking context](https://web.dev/learn/css/z-index/)

By moving the cloud image element to be a sibling of the text and person image elements, their z-indexes will cause them to overlap the way you want

```html
<div>
  <img
    class="slide__person"
    src="https://www.wikihow.com/images/6/61/Draw-a-Cartoon-Man-Step-15.jpg"
  />

  <p class="slide__text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    Aliquam architecto, corporis deserunt distinctio dolor dolores
    ea ex hic iste magnam nihil optio perferendis perspiciatis
  </p>
  <img class="banner__slider-cloud" src="../assets/cloud.png" />
</div>
```

```css
.slide .slide__person {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.slide .slide__text {
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 8px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.banner__slider-cloud {
  border: 1px solid;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 17%;
  top: 5%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

[updated codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-khayyam-9fyrdh?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:1888-2196)

Comment: I apologize in advance that I did not warn the cloud must remain static, it cannot be moved inside the slider

Answer (score 0):

Although I believe a full solution is impossible, due to the DOM manipulation that the Vue Slick Carousel library uses, there is a workaround to the `z-index` limitation using `transform-style: preserve-3d`.

So long as all the elements in the DOM hierarchy being manipulated have the `preserve-3d` CSS attribute applied (*this property is **not** automatically inherited*), you can use `transform: translateZ()` to sort elements' layering even when they are not siblings in the stacking context. See the edited snippet below.

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

/* ### Added this block ### */

.banner * {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.slick-slide>div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slide {
  max-width: 500px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.slide .slide__text {
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 8px;
  transform: translateZ(1px); /* ### Added this line ### */
}

.banner__slider-cloud {
  border: 1px solid;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="lending">
  <main class="banner">
    <div class="banner__slider">
      <div class="slide">
        <div>
          <img class="slide__person" src="https://www.wikihow.com/images/6/61/Draw-a-Cartoon-Man-Step-15.jpg" />

          <p class="slide__text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto, corporis deserunt distinctio dolor dolores ea ex hic iste magnam nihil optio perferendis perspiciatis
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <img class="banner__slider-cloud" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" />
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: I would be interested to hear if anyone finds a workaround that is compatible with the carousel library, or if they are able to definitively show (maybe through looking at the source code) that a workaround is impossible without changes in the dependency. I was unable to get the `preserve-3d` solution working with the carousel library.